# drawLine to write text MF

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make the letters MF using drawLine, but is struggling to connect the lines

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
    // Render the image.
    g.drawImage (image, 30,30, this);

    // INSERT YOUR CODE HERE:
    // Do your graffitti here. For example,
    g.drawLine(150,100,150,140);
    g.drawLine(150,0,150,0);
}
```

Comment: You are not showing us your actual attempt at drawing "MF" so we can't say why you can't connect the lines. Don't just give us your homework.

Comment: Your two lines aren't starting or ending at the same points, so why are you expecting them to connect? One of the zeros in the second line should be 100 or 140

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `drawString`:

```
 g.drawImage (image, 30,30, this);
 //set font size (optional)
 Font font = g.getFont().deriveFont( 20.0f ); 
 g.setFont( font );
 g.drawString("MF", 150, 100);
```

If you want to draw it line by line :

```
//draw M
g.drawLine(150,100,150,140); //from top left vertically down
g.drawLine(150,100,165,115); //from top left diagonally dowm
g.drawLine(165,115,180,100); //continue diagonally up
g.drawLine(180,100,180,140); //continue vertically down
//todo draw F
```

From the documentation:

> Draws a line, using the current color, between the points (x1, y1) and
> (x2, y2)in this graphics context's coordinate system.

so `g.drawLine(150,0,150,0)` draws a line between the same points (point 150,0  to point 150,0) which means it draws a **point** rather than a line.